# How do I use dplyr::arrange to sort NA's first?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to sort `flights` in ascending order of `dep_time` with `NA`s first using `dplyr`'s `arrange` in `dplyr_0.8.0`. `arrange`'s default is to list `NA`s last.

I had thought that

```
arrange(flights,desc(is.na(dep_time)),dep_time)
```

would work but `NA`s still come last. In fact, both

```
desc(is.na(dep_time))
```

and

```
is.na(dep_time)
```

produce the same arrangement. Why is this and how do I get the desired sort?

Edit: here's a minimal, reproducible example.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(x = sample(c(NA,NA,1:4)))
arrange(df,desc(is.na(x)),x)
arrange(df,is.na(x),x)
```

Here's the output.

```
...
> arrange(df,desc(is.na(x)),x)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
      x
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5    NA
6    NA
> arrange(df,is.na(x),x)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
      x
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5    NA
6    NA
```

It works as expected if I `mutate(ind = is.na(x))` and then sort on the variable `ind` rather than the expression `is.na(x)`.
Here's my [sessionInfo()](https://gist.github.com/cd4568f43df3e26c78e7c26546d6f135). All hints toward solution gratefully received.

Comment: Your `arrange(flights,desc(is.na(dep_time)),dep_time)` seems to work fine.

Comment: reproducible example please? Agree with @JuliusVainora  that I can't reproduce either with dplyr 0.7.8 and with `set.seed(101); flights <- tibble(dep_time=sample(c(NA,NA,1:4)))`

Comment: update: just installed dplyr 0.8.0, same results (i.e. `arrange(flights,desc(is.na(dep_time)),dep_time)` produces the expected output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by downloading the latest version of `dplyr_0.8.0`:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
```